# How to keep two iterators over map in java and remove keys in between without ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, concurrentmodification

I have to process a `Map <BitSet,List<List<Integer>> MyMap`

```
if (key1 contains all of corresponding true bits of key2)
     Remove from key2 all those values which are common with key1)
```

In this process, if the number of elements in a list drops below a THRESHOLD (user defined positive integer), it is removed. Also if the Map contains empty list, then corresponding key is removed.

I am using following code:

```
List<BitSet> keys = new ArrayList<>(MyMap.keySet());  
ListIterator it1=keys.listIterator();
while(it1.hasNext())  {
     BitSet key1=(BitSet)it1.next();
     ListIterator it2=keys.listIterator(it1.nextIndex());
     while(it2.hasNext()) {
         BitSet key2=(BitSet)it2.next();                 
         BitSet ankey=(BitSet)key1.clone();
         ankey.and(key2);    
         if(ankey.equals(key1)) {//key1 is subset and key2 is superset
               if(removePoints(key1,key2))  {
                     it1.remove();
                     break;
               }
         }
         else if(ankey.equals(key2))  {                           
              if(removePoints(key2,key1))  {
                    it2.remove();                         
              }
         }
     }
}

public static boolean removePoints(BitSet key1,BitSet key2)
 {
     List<List<Integer>> list1=MyMap.get(key1);         
     List<List<Integer>> list2=MyMap.get(key2);
     Boolean ret=false;         
     for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)  {                   
         List<Integer> sublist1=list1.get(i);            
         for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++)  {            
             List<Integer> sublist2=list2.get(j);                 
             sublist1.removeAll(sublist2);
             if(sublist1.isEmpty())
                 break;
         }
         if(sublist1.size()<=THRESHOLD)
             list1.remove(sublist1);
         if( list1.isEmpty()) {             
             MyMap.remove(key1); 
             ret=true;                 
         }
     }
     return ret;
 }
```

But the program is giving error:

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`
`at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification`
`at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next`

Also, am  not sure if this is the efficient way to code? As the Map contain ~2000 entries. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

A `ConcurrentModificationException` can happen when the underlying collection is modified after an `Iterator` is created, and that modification isn't done through the `Iterator` itself.

In your code as written, there is only one place where that can happen: the interation between `it1` and `it2`, which are iterators on the same collection.  Anytime you call `remove` on one, the other one will break the next time you call `next`.

There's a variety of ways to work around this, but one way is to separate what you're removing from your 'key' collection from the iteration of that collection, like so:

```
List<BitSet> allKeys = new ArrayList<>(MyMap.keySet());  
List<BitSet> removedKeys = new ArrayList<>();

for (ListIterator<BitSet> it1 = allKeys.listIterator(); it1.hasNext(); ) {
   BitSet key1 = it1.next();
   for (ListIterator<BitSet> it2 = allKeys.listIterator(it1.nextIndex()); it2.hasNext(); ) {
       BitSet key2 = it2.next();
       BitSet ankey=(BitSet)key1.clone();
       ankey.and(key2);    
       if(ankey.equals(key1)) {//key1 is subset and key2 is superset
           if(removePoints(key1,key2))  {
                 removedKeys.add(key1);
                 break;
           }
       }
       else if(ankey.equals(key2))  {                           
          if(removePoints(key2,key1))  {
                 removedKeys.add(key2);
                 break;
          }
       }
    }
}

allKeys.removeAll(removedKeys);
```

`allKeys` will then be in the state that you expect.  I assume that sometime later you would want to call `MyMap.keySet().retainAll()` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use iterator.remove() on the Map's keySet since it's only a "view" on the internal structure of the map.

But you can use an iterator on the map's entrySet(), where each element is an instance of Map.Entry containing all you map entries (key/value pairs). You can call iterator.remove() on this iterator, that will effectivly remove the corresponding key/value pair from the map.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(Integer.valueOf(0), "0");
map.put(Integer.valueOf(1), "1");
map.put(Integer.valueOf(2), "2");
map.put(Integer.valueOf(3), "3");
map.put(Integer.valueOf(4), "4");

System.out.println(map);

Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> entryIter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (entryIter.hasNext()) {
   Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = entryIter.next();
   if (entry.getKey().intValue() % 2 == 0)
       entryIter.remove();
}

System.out.println(map);
```

Hope that it helps.

Regards

Comment: You are incorrect about `Map.iterator().remove()`, at least in general.  [The interface specifies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) that remove is supported, although add is not.